# The requested profile "pom.xml" could not be activated because it does not exist in microservices project

Tags: java, maven, microservices, maven-plugin

I am getting this error "**The requested profile "pom.xml" could not be activated because it does not exist.**" every time I tried to run the maven goals like mvn clean install.

`mvn clean` is working but not `mvn clean install`.

I also tried with and without removing the pom.xml from active profiles..but it didn't work.

Also, I have three microservice maven sub-modules when I tried to run each of them separately they are also not running stating: "/microservices-parent/product-microservice/java/com/ecommproject/productservice/ProductServiceApplication" does not exist.

Can anybody please really help?

**ERROR MESSAGE**

`[INFO] Scanning for projects... [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Reactor Build Order: [INFO]  [INFO] microservices-parent                                               [pom] [INFO] product-microservice                                               [jar] [INFO] order-microservice                                                 [jar] [INFO] inventory-microservice                                             [jar] [INFO]  [INFO] -------------------< com.ecomm:microservices-parent >------------------- [INFO] Building microservices-parent 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT                       [1/4] [INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]--------------------------------- [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Reactor Summary for microservices-parent 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: [INFO]  [INFO] microservices-parent ............................... FAILURE [  0.010 s] [INFO] product-microservice ............................... SKIPPED [INFO] order-microservice ................................. SKIPPED [INFO] inventory-microservice ............................. SKIPPED [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time:  1.412 s [INFO] Finished at: 2023-04-09T22:15:41+05:30 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [WARNING] The requested profile "pom.xml" could not be activated because it does not exist. [ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "mvn". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1] [ERROR]  [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging. [ERROR]  [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles: [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException`

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ecomm</groupId>
    <artifactId>microservices-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>microservice-parent</name>
    <description>microservice-parent-project</description>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <modules>
        <module>microservice-product</module>
        <module>microservice-order</module>
        <module>microservice-inventory</module>
    </modules>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: do you have a `.mvn/maven.config` in your project? each item must be in separate line

Comment: @SlawomirJaranowski yes I have